# Advantage or disadvantage of using = operator or uniform initializer while using auto keyword

Tags: c++, programming-practices, c++11

Most examples of `auto` use the `=` operator.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto a = 1;
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

Why don't they use the uniform initializer like this?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto a {1};
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

Is there any advantage or disadvantage of using one syntax over another while using the `auto` keyword?

Comment: See e.g. the discussion in https://abseil.io/tips/88

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's one reason. Until C++17, `auto a {1};` *did the wrong thing* (probably). See, the assumption was that if you were using a braced-init-list to initialize a placeholder-declared variable, then you wanted to create an `initializer_list<T>`. So unless you wanted `a` to be an `initializer_list<int>` containing 1 value...

So only in C++17 does `auto a {1};` actually do the thing you (probably) wanted: `a` will be a genuine `int`. Of course, `auto a = {1};` will *still* be an `initializer_list<int>`, because that's totally obvious, right?

So yeah, probably best to stick with `auto a = 1;`.

Comment: I tried the second example with `auto a {1}` with `clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic foo.cpp && ./a.out` and I don't get a compiler error. It produces the output `1`. It seems to contradict your first point.

Comment: @LoneLearner: The behavior of compilers is irrelevant; only the *standard* matters. And if you look in [the C++11 standard](http://wg21.link/N3337), in [dcl.spec.auto]/6, you will see... that you (and Clang) are absolutely right ;)